# version change management in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

On updating app and publishing in windows phone marketplace,the phones do not show that update is available for some days.Is there any way to check the update in app from the code?

Comment: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Checking_for_updates_from_inside_a_Windows_Phone_app

Answer (score 1):

Im using [the one from LocalJoost](http://www.nuget.org/packages/wp7nl):

One of the biggest advanced: Zero lines of code solution for in-app checking for updates on Windows Phone

You can find [the complete documentation here](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.nl/2013/09/zero-lines-of-code-solution-for-in-app.html)

Comment: Am unable to get that Upgradecheckbehaviour box. I have added Wp7nl by using Nugget package.

Comment: As in Debug or in Production? If you meant debug: "Since in debug mode the app will run on you phone or emulator using a generated temporary app id, it won’t be possible to check for new versions anyway so I’ve added an #if statement around the actual check.". As for production can you share some code of the implementation? Else it would be for me running around in dark room... :)

Comment: My problem is that, I havent found the UpgradeCheckBehaviour box to be added to the main page. I am unable to do below step::                                                      "If you drop the UpgradeCheckBehavior, as I have christened this thing, onto the main page of your application, Blend will present you with only two options: a message box caption and a message box text"

Answer (score 0):

Launching the MarketPlace Details task should trigger the update.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017(v=vs.105).aspx

This article must be helpful-

[Checking for updates from inside a Windows Phone app](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Checking_for_updates_from_inside_a_Windows_Phone_app)